# Java array definitions

Tags: java, arrays

Was doing some multiple choices and one question gave the following array definitions and asking which are valid statements:

```
int[] array1, array2[];
int[][] array3;
int[] array4[], array5[];

A. array2 = array3;
B. array2 = array4;
C. array1 = array2;
D. array4 = array1;
E. array5 = array3;
```

And the correct answers are A,B,E. Why? I see array3 and array4 are 2 dimensional arrays and array1,2,5 are not.

Comment: Whether exams like this one will produce better programmers is something I'd dearly like to discuss with the examiner.

Comment: @laune they're not meant to provide better programmers, but to help programmers to spot these things and rewrite them.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  You are an optimist, but that's not a bad property ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split the definition of each variable per line and then you will realize how each operation compiles (or not):

```
int[] array1;
int[] array2[]; //which is int[][] array2
int[][] array3;
int[] array4[]; //which is int[][] array4
int[] array5[]; //which is int[][] array5
```

Now, you can easily evaluate these:

```
A. array2 = array3; //compiles
B. array2 = array4; //compiles
C. array1 = array2; //doesn't compile
D. array4 = array1; //doesn't compile
E. array5 = array3; //compiles
```

Also, in Java, there are not 2 dimensional arrays. You have array of arrays.

Comment: @DavidColer that's not 2d array, that's an array of arrays. And there's no 3d array, it's array of arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array1, array2[];
int[][] array3;
int[] array4[], array5[];
```

array1 is a single dimension array

array2 is now a 2dimension array as well as array4 and array 5
array3 is also declared as a 2d array

array 1 does not equal any other array in the list

array 2 can = array3, array4, or array5 and vice versa.